# IE 8 outline-width unspecified error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

Given this html element:

```
<input id="test" style = "outline-width: medium;" />
```

And this jQuery call:

```
console.log($('#test').css("outline-width"));
```

I see this in the console (IE 8):

> "Unspecified error."

jQuery 1.8.2 is included on the page (the version doesn't seem to matter), but I don't think it is a jQuery issue.

Try this fiddle out in IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/vAWB4/5/

Why does the call fail?  It works fine in every other browser I've tried, including IE9 set to the IE8 browser mode.

Comment: It's because IE8 not support outline-width property.

Comment: That would explain it... why wouldn't it just return "undefined" instead of throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 will throw an error when you use `"outline-width"` unless you specify a DOCTYPE. Also there is the option of using the `<meta>` tag to force it to run in IE8 Standard Mode.

Comment: I would add that there are other css properties that throw the same error.  Too bad IE8 can't just return "undefined", cause try catch blocks are expensive. Actually, I would rather IE8 return undefined altogether anytime anyone used it. :)